# Exporting output results from a model into the input of a different model

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to build a model of a factory using the personal learning edition of AnyLogic. Since this version has a limited number of blocks per model, building the full factory on a single model is presenting itself as an impossible task. In order to surpass this issue I want to split the factorys main processes into different models, which means I'll have to feed the output of process A into the input of process B.

My question is: how can I export a time stamped output of a model into the input of a different model?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options

Option 1: Through an Excel file (or txt file)

Simply link an Excel file in your model, using the object from the connectivity palette

Then you can get the data using code similar to below

```
int excelRow = 2;
String sheetName = "Sheet1!";
String cellName =  sheetName + "A" + excelRow;
while (excelFile.cellExists( cellName )) {
    int x = (int)excelFile.getCellNumericValue( sheetName + "A" +  excelRow);
    int b = (int)excelFile.getCellNumericValue( sheetName + "B" +  excelRow);
    int c = (int)excelFile.getCellNumericValue( sheetName + "C" +  excelRow);
    boolean d = excelFile.getCellBooleanValue( sheetName + "D" +  excelRow);
    
    excelRow ++; // Increase the row that we will lookup in the Excel
}
```

Just a while loop where you go from one excel line to the next as long as the line exists, and then do what ever is needed with the data

Option 2: AnyLogic Internal DB

Simply import your excel sheet to the AnyLogic DB and then loop over the entries in the table using a for loop

```
List<Tuple> rows = selectFrom(db_table).list();

for (Tuple row : rows) {
    traceln(
        row.get( db_table.db_column )
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi Jabo-Ben! First of all, thank you for answering! The solution you proposed to import results is working just fine, but I still don't understand how to export the results from a anylogic file into an excel file, can you help me with that? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Francisco, thank you for the feedback, glad my response answered your question. Please ask a new question but check out the help file first, here is one option of doing it from database - https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/export-excel.html#exporting-data-to-ms-excel-workbook - , or https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/excel-file.html#excel-file,  and then post what you have tried and what was the outcome. There are many options for exporting